# Is there anyway to get the hardware information on a hardware RAID 1 while inside of the OS?

Tags: gnome, hardware, raid

Is there any way to see the information on a hardware raid while still being in the OS?

Things to note:

- I am remotely connected to this machine (so I cannot physically see the information of both drives, but I do know that two drives are in this machine)
- I cannot reboot this machine as it is in production
- This unit was handed off to me, but I can gather more information as needed
- GUI: Gnome Version 2.30.0
- OS: Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where to start here.

1. Gnome is a GUI user environment, not an OS. try `lsb_release -a` to see what version of Linux you're running.
2. /dev/sda is the raid set and does not correspond to either physical disk. You do not have a master/slave relationship in raid 1 so saying "mirrored drive" and "normal drive" are meaningless.
3. You can check what kind of raid controller you have by running `lspci | grep -i raid`. You might also get the information through `dmesg`.
4. If you have an LSI controller you can probably download the megacli utility from http://www.lsi.com/support/Pages/download-search.aspx and use it to see the physical disks.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.   I have updated the original question.